# How to make a class instance in Swift copyable?

Tags: swift, nscopying

In Objective-C, you can make your class instance copyable by implementing NSCopying and copyWithZone:.  How do you do similar thing in Swift (without using Foundation)?

Comment: Write your own copy method.

Comment: But who can you create an instance of the same class as `self`? That is in cases where you implement `copyWithZone:` for different subclasses. I've been trying with `self.dynamicType` with no luck.

Comment: Here is an easy way to do it.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35915186/4757335