# Assign a variable by value, not by reference

Tags: swift

What is the best way to make a **copy** of a `class`, not a `struct` variable without making a reference to it's memory location.

For example

```
    class Person {
        var name: String = ""
        var age: Int = 0

        init(name: String, age: Int) {
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
        }

        var mapped: [String: Any] {
            return [
                "name": self.name,
                "age": self.age
            ]
        }
    }

    var person: Person = Person(name: "Hitchhiker", age: 42)

    var personCopy = person

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "a_person": person.mapped,

            "c_personCopy": personCopy.mapped
        ]
    }

    print("Original:", dictionary.jsonStringValue)

    person.age = 100
    person.name = "Guide"

    print("\n\n========\n\n")
    print("Edit 1:", dictionary.jsonStringValue)

    personCopy.age = 200
    personCopy.name = "To the Galaxy"

    print("\n\n========\n\n")
    print("Edit 2:", dictionary.jsonStringValue)

// I have this swift extension to make my logs better, don't mind the implicit unwrapping.
extension Dictionary {
    var jsonStringValue: String {
        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: .prettyPrinted)
        return String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    }
}
```

This prints an output which looks like this.

```
Original: {
  "a_person" : {
    "name" : "Hitchhiker",
    "age" : 42
  },
  "c_personCopy" : {
    "name" : "Hitchhiker",
    "age" : 42
  }
}


========


Edit 1: {
  "a_person" : {
    "name" : "Guide",
    "age" : 100
  },
  "c_personCopy" : {
    "name" : "Guide",
    "age" : 100
  }
}


========


Edit 2: {
  "a_person" : {
    "name" : "To the Galaxy",
    "age" : 200
  },
  "c_personCopy" : {
    "name" : "To the Galaxy",
    "age" : 200
  }
}
```

If I manipulate the values of the copies, the originals will also be, updated because the copies are assigned by reference.

I know I can create something like an extension function which makes a `copy` of the original variable, like this.

```
extension Person {
    func copy() -> Person {
        return Person(name: self.name, age: self.age)
    }
}

var person = Person(name: "Jon Snow", age: 0)
var personCopy = person.copy()
personCopy.name = "Jon Targaryen" // this is now a value copy.
```

But how can I do this easier without creating a lot of boilerplate code for a lot of different models?

**Update**:

I know that I can use **Swift Protocols** here, for example

```
protocol Copying {
    init(original: Self)
}

extension Copying {
    func copy() -> Self {
        return Self.init(original: self)
    }
}
```

Which I saw in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45636100/5928180), but I'd have to subclass my Model classes to these, which may cause some problems since my Model is already a subclass and it wants me to implement some of these boilerplate **initializers** and I don't want that

Answer (score 2):

Classes are reference types. The only way to get a copy is to define a `copy` method as you have or to create an `init` method that takes another instance to be copied (which is essentially the same as your `copy` method).

You really should consider making your model classes as `struct` instead of `class` as long as you don't need inheritance. Then you get the copy semantics automatically.

Comment: I use inheritance with my models which is why I am using `class`, and the `copy()` method. There's just this one use case which needs me to have a `value` copy of the variable.