# How to use Self for method return types in Swift?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift4.1

This code produces Xcode error messages that lead you in a circle. Let's say I have a protocol called `Marker` and I'd like Markers to copy themselves. Here's a first guess...

```
protocol Marker {
    func copy() -> Self
}
class Marker1 : Marker {
    func copy() -> Self {
        return Marker1()   // error here
    }
}
```

(I'm not sure how to use `Self` correctly, because I can't find it in the *The Swift Programming Language* document. If you know where it's documented, please include that in answer.)

That code gives an error on the marked line: `Cannot convert return expression of type 'Marker1' to return type 'Self'` and it suggests a fix: `Insert ' as! Self'`.

I accept the fix:

```
...
    return Marker1() as! Self
...
```

This leads to another compiler error: `'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class; did you mean 'Marker1'?`

If I accept that "fix" it goes back to the original error. I'd call that a bug in Xcode. Let's try something else:

```
func copy() -> Marker1 {
    return Marker1()
}
```

Another error: `` Method 'copy()' in non-final class 'Marker1' must return `Self` to conform to protocol 'Marker' ``

Making the class `final` does fix the error. But is there a way to do this without making a class final? And where is `Self` documented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With such a hierarchy, you would have to make the class conforming to the protocol `final`:

```
protocol Marker {
    func copy() -> Self
}
final class Marker1 : Marker {
    func copy() -> Marker1 {
        return Marker1()
    }
}
```

The `final` is needed because when you don't apply `final` and you create a subclass `Marker2: Marker1` then copy would not return the correct class `Self` any more.

You can workaround that by creating a `required` initializer and always create the correct instance:

```
protocol Marker {
    init()
    func copy() -> Self
}
class Marker1 : Marker {
    required init() {
    }
    func copy() -> Self {
        let copy = type(of: self).init()
        return copy
    }
}
```

(original code removed because does not work)

Related: [Implementing copy() in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242629/implementing-copy-in-swift)

Comment: This answers my questions but unfortunately the copy constructor in the protocol, which I like, leads to the dreaded: `Protocol 'Marker' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`. Maybe I'll create an `AnyMarker` wrapper thingy.

Comment: @RobN It works for me exactly as I have written it but I have just noted it doesn't actually work correctly for subclasses therefore I have removed it for now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your current implementation is that `Self` is an abstract type, so you cannot simply return a concrete type, such as `Marker1` from a function with a return type of `Self`. If you changed the return type to `Marker1`, you'd need to make your class final to ensure that no subclass can override the method, since in a subclass, `Self` would correspond to the subclass type. However, this is still not good since in this case the subclass won't conform to the protocol, since in a subclass of `Marker1`, the return type of `Marker1` is not the same as `self`.

You can solve this problem by getting the metatype of your current class using `type(of: self)`, then calling a designated initializer on the metatype, which will indeed return an instance of type `Self`. The final step is to create a required initializer for your class to ensure that all subclasses need to implement the same initializer that's called in your `copy()` method in order to make `copy` work for subclasses as well.

```
protocol Marker {
    func copy() -> Self
}

class Marker1 : Marker {
    func copy() -> Self {
        let result = type(of: self).init()
        return result
    }

    required init() {}
}
```